# Changing a local variable in a function from another function

Tags: python, function, variables, scope

First, here's my example code:

**EDIT: I should have specified, in my real code, that_func() is already returning another value, so I want it to return one value, and change c in addition**

**EDIT 2: Code edited to show what I mean**

```
def this_func():
    c=1   # I want to change this c
    d=that_func()
    print(c, d)

def that_func():
     this_func.c=2 #Into this c, from this function
     return(1000) #that_func should also return a value

this_func()
```

What I want to do is change the local variable c in this_func() **to the value I assign it in that_func()**, so that it prints 2 instead of 1.

From what I've gathered online, *this_func.c=2* should do just that, but it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong, or have I misunderstood?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: `this_func` is a function, not a class. `c` is a local variable to that function - if it were a class instead, it would work like your question suggests. But that requires some changes to how you are doing things..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in an object and pass it to `that_func`:

```
def this_func():
    vars = {'c': 1}
    d = that_func(vars)
    print vars['c'], d

def that_func(vars):
    vars['c'] = 2
    return 1000
```

Alternatively, you can pass it in as a regular variable and `that_func` can return multiple values:

```
def this_func():
    c = 1
    c, d = that_func(c)
    print c, d

def that_func(c):
    c = 2
    return c, 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you misunderstood.

`functions` are not `class`. You can't access variables of a `function` like that.

Obviously, it's not the smartest of code that can be written, but this code should give an idea about how to use variables of a function.

```
def this_func():
    c=1   # I want to change this c
    c=that_func(c) # pass c as parameter and receive return value in c later
    print(c)

def that_func(b): # receiving value of c from  this_func()
    b=2  # manipulating the value
    return b #returning back to this_func()

this_func()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified, in my real code, that_func() is already returning another value, so I want it to return one value, and change c in addition. I have edited the question.

Comment: You can always return more than one value and unpack them later. Is it ok?